# Why does AWS Global Accelerator use anycast internally?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Please explain the request flow and how anycast is used in the architecture?

P.S. I have searched the everywhere on why anycast was used in the internal architecture of AWS Global Accelerator. Got the answer after speaking to a few experts. Hence answered it myself so that it would be useful to the community. More answers are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Global Accelerator is a service that is designed to improve the availability and performance of applications that are running in multiple AWS Regions. When you create a Global Accelerator, it provides you with two anycast IP addresses that you can use as entry points for your application traffic. These anycast IP addresses are advertised over the internet through Border Gateway Protocol (BGP), which means that they are announced from multiple AWS Edge Locations.

Here's how the traffic flow works:

[image]

A client initiates a request to access your application. The request is sent to the anycast IP address that you have configured as the entry point for your application traffic.

The anycast IP address is advertised over the internet through BGP. When the client sends the request to the anycast IP address, BGP routes the traffic to the closest AWS Edge Location that is announcing the anycast IP address.

The traffic reaches the AWS Edge Location that is closest to the client. This is the first point of contact between the client and the AWS network.

The traffic is then sent to the Global Accelerator endpoint that is associated with your application. The Global Accelerator routes the traffic to the optimal AWS Region based on your endpoint group configuration.

The traffic reaches your application in the AWS Region that you have configured. The response is then sent back to the client through the same path.

The key benefit of using anycast IP addresses is that it allows the traffic to be routed to the closest AWS Edge Location, which helps reduce latency and improve performance. Additionally, the Global Accelerator uses health checks to monitor the health of your endpoints, and automatically routes traffic to healthy endpoints. This helps improve the availability of your application.